SCA Scan identified MySQL vulnerablity in dojo 1.17.3
We recently turned on SCA Scan for an older web application. The scan identified a need to upgrade to the latest version of dojo 1.17.3. The scan is now identifying a number of High and medium vulnerabilities due to what appears to be a dependency on MySQL version 8.0.21. The application in question has no database connection or dependency on database. Is there any way to either update the MySQL version or pull out all the MySQL dependencies. As a side note there is no direct reference in the dojo library for MySQL.
